# How to set image src with alias in Vue3 + Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm making a project with Vue3 + Vite and trying to set an adaptive src for the img:

```
<img :src="`@img/map_icons/${ currentMap.title }_icon.png`">
```

In vite.config i've created the alias:

```
'@img': resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/assets/img')
```

But website doesn't load my img and giving an error:

```
GET http://localhost:5173/@img/map_icons/ancient_icon.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The only way i find to do it correctly is by using relative src:

```
<img :src="`./../../shared/assets/img/map_icons/${ currentMap.title }_icon.png`">
```

So how can i set the src with using alias?

Comment: try this
`import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@img': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})`

Comment: @Jazuly This doesn't differ from resolve() in a way it works